# Why is my curl request not uploading the file even though it exists?

Tags: php, curl

I have a script `backup_script.sh` that gets run automatically every night, the contents of script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
##Create a backup directory for the current day
mkdir /home/test_manager_backups/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

##Backup the database to the current day's database
#this command backs up the db, it's been removed from this example

##Backup any files in the /uploads directory to the current day's database
cd /home/test_manager_backups/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/ && tar -zcvf files.tar.gz /var/www/html/tests_manager/uploads

##Remove backups that are 7 days old so that the folder does not get cluttered
cd /home/test_manager_backups/ && rm -rf `date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "7 day ago"`

##Compress the backup into "most recent" backup file
cd /home/test_manager_backups/ && tar -zcvf most_recent_backup.tar.gz `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

##Post the most recent backup file to an off-site server
curl -F "file=@/home/test_manager_backups/most_recent_backup.tar.gz" -u "hfletcher:Pa$$w0rd" https://inbound.q-site.co.uk/backup/store
```

The curl requests should be posting the file to the server, there is a PHP file that processes the upload.

I tried to find out why the file wasn't being uploaded, right at the start of the php file at `/backup/store`, I put:

```
print_r( $_FILES );
```

but it was empty.

I know the file exists, as I can browse to `/home/test_manager_backups/most_recent_backup.tar.gz` and it contains the files to upload. I just don't understand why `$_FILES` is blank on the PHP script, even though my curl uploads the file.

Comment: What's you get, if you do the curl line in console.

Comment: @KrisRoofe same thing, just returns `[]` from the php script

Comment: I mean the output of curl?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, SSL handshake OK, 200 response received, content type multipart/form-data, auth ok, "Connection #0 to host inbound.q-site.co.uk left intact", transfer encoding: chunked ( i checked this because file is large)